# How to modify the following circuit (using only BC108 transistors) so that two LEDs light up when the motor is moving between position A-B and B-C

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

[image]

I need to modify the circuit included in this post so that one LED lights up when the rotary switch (central left) is set to the middle point, and the motor is running, while another one lights up when the rotary switch is set to the furthest left position and the motor is running.

How could I do this using only BC108 transistors, resistors, and of course the two LEDs?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or homework-answering service. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work, own findings and own ideas on this considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Hint, when the motor is running, there's a voltage across it.